# Could not load file or assembly "*.dll" , The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

[Exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgHvM.png)

I am pretty sure the `C:/test/AdPlatform.Shared.dll` is exist.
When I run this in `Rider/VisoStudio`, it works well.
When I try to run it as a system service, it does not work. There is no error and it creates null instance.

Comment: AdPlatform.Shared.dll is come from 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom Reference of Assemblies/DLL in any project will work only in Local Machine, not in other machine/Environments

***ADDING THIRD PARTY DLLs IN ANY PROJECT FROM LOCAL PATH IS ALWAYS RISKER***

**Correct Way:**

1. [Registering the Custom DLL in GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182316/how-do-i-register-a-net-dll-file-in-the-gac) then Add the reference from SYSTEM PATH
2. For Web service/MVC Related Project(s) [creating custom folders(lib) in the Solution itself and adding the DLL from that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685718/how-to-add-dll-in-c-sharp-project) will be the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a external library in your solution you need to place its file in a place the solution can access from anywhere (aka deploy location), meaning, put the file in a solution folder and set its `using` statements to its `namespace` anywhere you reference it in your project(s), so it will be sure to find the library you need.