# Winforms C# : Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll'

Tags: c#, aforge

I made a screen recorder that relies on the `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll`.
After getting the package `AForge.Video` from the NuGet package manager I find it doesn't include the `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll`, just the AForge.Video.dll. I decided to manually add the `FFMPEG.dll` into my program folder and make a reference to it.

However now I get this error message:

[image: My error message]

I have tried following many solutions, but they don't seem to refer to my issue.

(Just because i know this will be the top suggestion, yes it is running in x86)

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: I would love to provide more information, I just don't know what. So if you need it to solve the issue i would gladly provide it.

Comment: Afaik you should now use `Accord.Video` and `Accord.Video.FFPMEG`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AForge.NET** is now basically deprecated and replaced by [**Accord.NET**](http://accord-framework.net/). As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord.NET) says about Accord.NET:

> The project was originally created to extend the capabilities of the AForge.NET Framework, but has since incorporated AForge.NET inside itself. Newer releases have united both frameworks under the Accord.NET name.

So if you are looking for the FFMPEG capabilities, you should reference [`Accord.Video.FFMPEG`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.Video.FFMPEG/) package from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.Video.FFMPEG/).

```
Install-Package Accord.Video.FFMPEG -Version 3.8.0
```

If you for some reason have to keep using AForge, try to follow the steps in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7685861/732221) to include the DLL properly in the project.

Comment: When trying with version 3.8.0 shows exception "System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG, Version=3.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fa1a88e29555ccf7' or one of its dependencies. Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019)'"