# Reference not found

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I've added a reference to my project. It's a PixelEngine.dll and the issue is, that whenever I call a constructor, there is an Exception `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`. I checked the path and the dll is in the directory.

**Code sample:**

```
using PixelEngine;
using System;

namespace Herni_Engine3D
{
    public class RandomPixels : Game
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Vytvořit instanci:
            RandomPixels Konzola = new RandomPixels();
            //Okno:
            Konzola.Construct(200, 200, 4, 4); //<<Here it crashes
            //Spustit:
            Konzola.Start();
        }
        //Každý snímek:
        public override void OnUpdate(float elapsed)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ScreenWidth; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ScreenHeight; j++)
                {
                    Draw(i, j, Pixel.Random());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you add the PixelEngine, maybe that is more interesting to know how?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to solve it, but your problem description is a bit inaccurate.

It is true you get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, but you should have provided the whole exception description:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at PixelEngine.Sprite.Load(String path)
   at PixelEngine.Font.CreateRetro()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at PixelEngine.Font.op_Implicit(Presets p)
   at PixelEngine.Game.Construct(Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 pixWidth, Int32 pixHeight, Int32 frameRate)
```

The issue is not that your dll is not included, but the issue saying that your code is looking for `System.Drawing.Common` and that is easy, you can install `System.Drawing.Common` from NuGet packages.

So that your project has following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When that is done, the issue is gone, of course, you will get a new issue that it is asking for `PixGL.dll`, which I really do not have, I guess you should have it.

Some reference to my founds:

- https://github.com/DevChrome/Pixel-Engine/blob/master/Libraries/PixelEngine.dll
- https://github.com/KROIA/Pixelengine
- [How to add dll in c# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685718/how-to-add-dll-in-c-sharp-project)